# How to identify the range of lines before the specified range in c# word interop

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I have identified a range in a word document through identifying the range of a certain word using the following code:

```
object start = 0, end = 0;
Word.Range myRange = doc.Range(ref start, end);
if(myRange.Find.Execute("wordtofind"))
{
    //some codes here
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way I can find to get the range of a specific line in the document that is 3 lines/paragraphs before that "wordtofind"?

Note:

The "wordtofind" is the only word in that particular line where it can be found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Range.MoveEnd` method to move the Range "backwards" by a certain number of specified units (see the `Word.WdUnits` enumeration).

To move back 3 paragraphs:

```
object unitPara as Word.WdUnits.wdParagraph;
object moveBack3 = -3;
myRange.MoveEnd(ref unitPara, ref moveBack3);
```